# Worksheet_Change not firing due to Application.EnableEvents = False?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a work order template for use by many users, that is intended to be an add-in that can generate a work order worksheet, where users will have the ability to edit certain information on the sheet and related cells will change accordingly. Currently, the add-in generates the new worksheet and adds the Worksheet_Change code programmatically. This was working correctly originally, until I added a more target cells as fail-safes in case someone accidentally edits the wrong cell. What is happening now, is that the add-in will create the worksheet as intended, but the target cells will not trigger the Worksheet_Change anymore.

I believe that the issue is Application.EnableEvents = False is turning off the Worksheet_Change events, but Application.EnableEvents = True is not turning the events back on afterwards in the code. Application.EnableEvents = True activates the Worksheet_Change again in the Immediate Window, but not in the code. I am fairly certain the code is in the same format it was when working, it just has more target cells. Am I adding Application.EnableEvents = True in the wrong place?

Here is the Worksheet_Change portion of the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call addIDValue
        Call ChangeIDD7
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("F7:G7")) Is Nothing Then
        Call addCSDValue
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C18")) Is Nothing Then
        Call addIDValue
        Call ChangeIDC18
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C20")) Is Nothing Then
        Call addCSDValue
        Call ChangeCSDC20
        Call ChangeG9

    'several more ElseIf statements cut for brevity

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint on the first line in the sub it never gets hit?  Even after running `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate pane?  I've never seen that happen.  Your `Application.EnableEvents = True` is fine as long as there's nothing weird going on in any of the subs you call (such as calling `End` for example, or anything else which would cause the VBA to abruptly stop running)

Comment: you could check that by putting a stop prior to the `Application.EnableEvents = True` and ensure that stop is triggered whenever a change is made

Comment: Thank you Tim, yes it does get hit after running EnableEvents in the Immediate pane. However, I would like for it to run without having to do that since the plan is to give this template to people who won't know how to do that. The addin creates the sheet, then adds the code to the new sheet's code module from a string, but now is not firing until I manually run EnableEvents.

Comment: I figured it out, the code kept breaking because I forgot to add Application.EnableEvents in one of the modules that was trying to add a formula to one of the target cells. That's why it used to work, but only stopped working after I added fail-safes, since I forgot to account for older code that targeted one of the new target cells. Thank you for the help.